# OpenWrt - settings lost after reboot

Tags: wireless-networking, router, openwrt

I flashed the official OpenWrt 15.05 firmware to a UBNT Rocket M5 device. The network functions worked normally.

Once I reboot or poweroff the device, all settings and configurations, including passwords, network interface settings, and packages installed with `opkg install`, etc, are gone.

I tried to flash a lower version 14.07 firmware, the flash process finished normally, but when I log to `192.168.1.1`, the system was still 15.05, and, with my password gone.

So, any idea about what's wrong?

Comment: "So, any idea about what's wrong?" - You need to perform a 30/30/30 Hard Reset and/or if your router has a primary and secondary firmware, perform the actions to switch.  Did you use a .bin or .img to perform the downgrade?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm new to OpenWrt. I used a .bin to perform the downgrade, and as I know this router has no second firmware

Comment: You perform the standard 30/30/30 Hard Reset after you loaded the .bin file, in order to downgrade, you might have to perform manually apply .img by ssh'ing into your router.  Check openwrt documentation to determine how to do both